# Cannot resolve unit name in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm a beginner here and am trying to get to grips with some code someone developed for me in Delphi in Rad Studio. I can't work out if when the developer sent the code he left something out or he used classes from elsewhere that I need to download from somewhere.

Either way, there are red squiggly lines underneath most of the 'uses' and the program won't run. These are the uses (some are missing, some not):

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, Vcl.Menus, 
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Imaging.JPEG, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, 
  Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.ShlObj, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, 
  cxGraphics, cxControls, cxLookAndFeels, cxLookAndFeelPainters, dxSkinsCore, 
  cxPCdxBarPopupMenu, cxShellCommon, cxButtons, cxCustomData, cxFilter, cxStyles,
  cxDataStorage, cxEdit, cxTextEdit, cxCalendar, cxContainer, cxSpinEdit,  
  cxMaskEdit, cxDropDownEdit, cxData, cxMemo, dxSkinVS2010, dxSkinscxPCPainter,
  CoolTrayIcon, AdvEdit, AdvEdBtn, HotKeyManager, uPrintersMonitor
```

Any help will be massively appreciated. Also when I open the project it does say 'Class xxxxxx not found. Ignore the error and continue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He used these external packages:

- [Developer Express VCL Controls](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/) Maybe not all of them, from the look of the uses clause only some basic packages;
- [CoolTrayIcon](http://subsimple.com/delphi.asp) (free);
- [AdvEdit from TMS software](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aspnet_advedit.asp);
- [HotKeymanager](http://subsimple.com/delphi.asp) (free).

Make sure these are all installed on the system (check Components/Install Packages in the IDE to see if they're already there).

Answer (score 3):

The `cxXXX` and `dxXXX` units are units from devExpress. You need to install the appropriate devExpress code/components to resolve this.

This may involve a purchase if you don't already have the devExpress components. In which case you will need to talk to the developer to find out which specific components are used by this project.

The `AdvXXX` units are TMS components. Same advice as for devExpress.

As for `HotKeyManager`, `CoolTrayIcon`, `uPrintersMonitor`, I suspect that they are part of the project that you have inherited. Update: I guessed wrong, the first two are 3rd party, linked to from Jan's answer.

One final point. I don't understand why you are asking here as your first port of call. If a developer has produced some code for you, it is that developer that you should be talking to. We can guess and reverse engineer to a degree, but the author of the code should know what its dependencies are.

Comment: I'm wondering about that `CoolTrayIcon` used in Delphi XE2. And there's some extra `HotKeyManager`.

Comment: @TLama Probably they are part of the project.

Comment: @TLama yeah, David Heffernan is right. It's about Systray routines.

Comment: @Bogdan, what are Systray routines ? I don't get that. With my comment I meant, that `CoolTrayIcon` is useless in Delphi XE2. You have already a tray icon component there, so there's nothing cool on it anymore.

Comment: @TLama Exactly. `CoolTrayIcon` is obsolete now.

Answer (score 0):

The coder gave you the source code, but he didn't give you the additional libraries and packages, or he did give you the additional libraries and packages but you didn't install them in your Delphi (e.g. **CoolTrayIcon** is a package relating to program operation in SysTray).

> Also when I open the project it does say 'Class xxxxxx not found. Ignore the error and continue?

The answer is, of course, no. Install the missing packages, get the additional libraries he used and add them to your project and everything should work fine.